# Using getopt to process simple command line arguments

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, getopt

I want to process some command line options.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char c;
  int n = 10000;
  int nThreads = 3;

  while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "n:t:")) != -1){
    switch (c)
      {
      case 'n':
        n = *optarg;
        break;
      case 't':
        nThreads = *optarg;
        break;
      default:
        abort();
      }
  }

  printf("n=%d, nThreads=%d\n", n, nThreads);
}
```

But this does not work as I expect. Running `./program -n 10000 -t 2` will cause the program to output `n=49, nThreads=50`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = atoi(optarg);
```

Otherwise you are assigning `char` to an `int`.

Also you can see from where the `49` and `50` is coming from.

Ascii value of char `1` is `49` and `2` is `50`.